# Something preventing default (explorer-style) CListCtrl jump to line behaviour

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm maintaining an MFC/COM/ATL 45-odd project solution originally written with VS6. I'm now using VS2008. 
I'm looking at a list control(vanilla CListCtrl) which doesn't behave as we think it should.
Normally in an MFC list control you can press a key, (Q say) & selection will jump down to the 1st line beginning with 'Q' (like windows explorer). Does anyone have an idea as to why this might not happen?
The styles/Extended styles are set the same as another control in the same project, which DOES work OK.
 Do I have to send my own message, or is there a flag, etc. that controls that functionality or what? Normally Google would supply the answer, but I haven't been able to frame my query correctly to come up with the relevant info this time.
Here's the line from the .rc file for the CListCtrl that doesn't jump to a line on keypress:

```
 CONTROL         "List1",IDC_BAL_LIST,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,0,73,493,230
```

And here's a line from the same .rc file showing a list control that does do that:

```
CONTROL         "List1",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,1,38,501,219
```

As you can see, there's no obvious difference to the properties, so what program code would affect it?

Comment: The obvious difference is in the ID values, how are they handled in the code?

Comment: They're both bound to CListCtrl member variables & manipulated using these variables. I've just scanned through both relevant sections of code, & they both have the same ExtendedStyles assigned - LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES. I can't see any differences between them. Its difficult to show all the code as its spread over 2-3000 LOC in each .cpp - I was hoping that someone might suggest a way that this functionality could be turned off.If I knew that it'd be a good start point, e.g does this property have a name etc.

Comment: There can't be many things that would prevent this feature from working - its just I can't find the info anywhere - surely there's an MFC guru out there who can tell me the (probably obvious) answer to why up,down,PgUp,PgDn,End & Home all work, but press 'B' & jump to 'B'- forget it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now realised what the problem is (coming back to it after a break) - CListCtrl matches on Column ZERO(the "label" column as some have called it I think) - which is a hidden column(in this particular list control) that sometimes contains a number & sometimes is blank, so unsuprisingly doesn't do anything when an alpha key is pressed. Obvious,really - I apologise for making the problem sound more complicated that it actually was ;)